# jQuery click runs checked condition before box is checked

Tags: jquery, click

my jQuery check box .on('click') code runs even before the check trigger is initiated/very confusing! so, when the checkbox loads, and i click it, that code runs. but when the page is simply loaded, the sql inside the inner test "if box is checked", runs. here is the code:

```
jQuery('#chk_uploaded').on('click', function (event) {  
     if (jQuery('#chk_uploaded').is(':checked') != true) {
     //window.alert("checked - activityid, approveddate, session['lm_required] = <?php echo $Activity_ID?>, 20<?php echo $FY ?>-06-30, <?php echo $_SESSION['lm_required'] ?>");
     <?php
        $set_lm_required_SQL = "UPDATE cpy_activity SET lm_required = 1 WHERE activityid = " . $Activity_ID . " and approveddate > '20" . $FY . "-06-30' ";
        $set_lm_required_RESULT = mssql_query($set_lm_required_SQL); 
      ?>
        window.alert("<?php echo $set_lm_required_SQL ?>");
        } else {
            window.alert("unchecked");
            <?php
                $reset_lm_required_SQL = "UPDATE cpy_activity SET lm_required = " . $_SESSION['lm_required'] . " WHERE activityid = " . $Activity_ID . " and approveddate > '20" . $FY . "-06-30' ";
                $reset_lm_required_RESULT = mssql_query($set_lm_required_SQL);
            ?>
                window.alert("<?php echo $reset_lm_required_SQL ?>");
                }
 });
```

basically, i caught $_SESSION var earlier, so that when the user checks the box again[unchecks] then i can reset the lm_required var back to what it was originally.

so the code pops the 'checked' alert when the box is checked, and 'unchecked' when unchecked. when i put sql code inside each condition, it alerts the sql statement just fine. then, when i commit the sql to run the result, and simply load the page, the sql sets the var to 1. that is, i query using msSEM and the value = 0. i simply load the page, and the value = 1, before i check the box. any ideas why?

Comment: you can add onchange event on checkbox instead of click event.

Comment: PHP is executed on the server, JavaScript on the client. Those are two distinct "worlds"

Comment: thx, Pandhi - i kept "click" but then referred to an ajax function for the fix. 

Andreas thx, too, for taking the time to reply. suggestion - add to your comment: "a safe way to use those worlds together is via Ajax - post to a url which takes care of the SQL. that way you keep them separate, yet get done your SQL when it's supposed to happen." then i would go look at Ajax. which i did, and got it working. people come here from different levels, and valuable are those responses who help direct the user forward.

Answer (score 0):

what's needed here is to, at the coaching of Andreas, separate the JavaScript and PHP worlds ==> using jQuery with a .ajax function. this code sums up basically what i did:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<?php

$FY=16;
$Activity_ID=12345;

?>
<script language="javascript">
    jQuery.ajax({
   url: "ajax_test2.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {fy: <?php echo $FY; ?>, acid: <?php echo $Activity_ID; ?>},
   success: function(response){
      // alert $result from the php page which is called response here.
      alert(response);
   }
});
</script>

</body></html>
```

then in ajax_test2.php:

```
 <?php
$hostname_sqldata = "db server name here";
$database_sqldata = "db name here";
$username_sqldata = "username here";
$password_sqldata = "password here";
$sql_conn = mssql_connect($hostname_sqldata, $username_sqldata, $password_sqldata);

if ( ! $sql_conn ) {
echo "MS SQL connection error: $hostname_sqldata == " . mssql_get_last_message() ;
exit ;
}

if ( !mssql_select_db( $database_sqldata, $sql_conn ) ) {
    die('MS SQL : Unable to select database!');
}

if ($_POST['fy'] != null && $_POST['acid'] != null ){
 $fy = $_POST['fy'];
$acid = $_POST['acid'];

$set_lm_required_SQL = "UPDATE table_name SET lm_required = 1 where activityid = $acid";
$set_lm_required_result = mssql_query($set_lm_required_SQL);

$get_lm_required_SQL = "SELECT * FROM cpy_activity WHERE activityid = $acid";
$get_lm_required_result = mssql_query($get_lm_required_SQL);

$row = mssql_fetch_array($get_lm_required_result);
$lm_required = $row['lm_required'];
$result = "fy/acid/lm_required: " . $fy . "/" . $acid . "/" . $lm_required . "";

//$result = $set_lm_required_SQL;

}else{
    // either of the values doesn't exist
    $result = "No Data Was Sent !";
}
// returning $result which is either 15 or " no data was sent "
echo $result;
?>
```

i hope i got in all the 4-space code spacing. check the parens for proper pairing, but that's the code i used for successful test. thx, All for your input!